# How to format the rows of only selected columns of df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'],
                   'B': [134.532, 543.009],
                   'C': [1.98, 0.9],
                   'D': [300.99, 7000.89]
```

})
Output:

```
     A        B     C
0  foo  134.532  1.98
1  bar  543.009  0.90
```

I want to format/round every row of the columns B and C to have 0 decimal places.

I do not want to change the original df to contain only these columns, that is, the formatting of the others needs to stay.

**And I need to select the columns by their index** because I have many columns, that I can't manually select by manually typing their headers.

I have tried:

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, 1:].map('{:,.0f}'.format)
```

But Im getting: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'. Did you mean: 'mad'?`

Comment: you can use `applymap` instead of `map`, but the type becomes string, do you want this? if you want keep numerical values, then `df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(int)` may work

Comment: also I'm surprised the error include `Did you mean: mad?` never saw this in an error message

Comment: Before your comment, I was, in fact, mad.

Comment: If these are only a couple of all the columns in the df, how can I make this change inplace if I don't want to format the other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to round the value i.e., .5 will round up and then drop the decimal (0) part

```
df[['B','C']]=df[['B','C']].round(0).astype(int)
df
```

```
    B   C
0   135     2
1   543     1
```

using index location

```
# choose all rows, and columns from 1 and onward
df.iloc[:,1:]=df.iloc[:,1:].round(0).astype(int)
df
```

```
    A   B   C
0   foo     135     2
1   bar     543     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = df.round({"B":0,"C":0})
```

You can change dictionary values for nay number of decimal places for each column

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the line:

```
df[['B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: np.around(x, decimals=2), axis=0)
```

for two decimal digits....